# Add background color when data changes with Vue

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, drag-and-drop

I have 3 containers where the first two of them have a drag and drop function, so that when I drop an element there, it changes that container color. This works correctly, but what I want to do is that when the 1st and 2nd container have a color, the 3rd one automatically updates to a new color. I am using Vuejs.

For instance: Container 1 has red color and container 2 has yellow color. The 3rd container would automatically update to an orange color. This would happen everytime I change the color of the containers.

This is my code:

HTML

```
 <!-- the containers where I drop the elements --> 
          <div class="box-flex">
              <div class="box" @dragover.prevent @drop="drop" id="box-1"></div>
              <div class="box" @dragover.prevent @drop="drop2" id="box-2"></div>
              <div class="box" id="box-3"></div>
          </div>
      <!-- the elements I want to drag -->
      <div v-for="(flower, i) in flowers" :key="i">
          <div v-if="flower_type == flower.type">
            <p>{{ flower.type }}</p>

            <p v-for="(color, j) in flower.colors" :key="j">
              <span
                :id="flower.type + '-' + color"
                :draggable="true"
                @dragstart="dragStart"
                @dragover.stop
              >{{ color }}</span>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
```

SCRIPT

```
 data() {
        return {
          //flowers
          flowers: [
            {
              type: "Cosmos",
              colors: ["red", "yellow", "orange", "black", "pink", "white"]
            },
          ],
        };
      },

      methods: {
        dragStart(e) {
          let target = e.target;
          e.dataTransfer.setData("color_id", target.id);
          e.dataTransfer.setData("box_el", target);
          let box1 = document.getElementById("box-1");
        },
        //first container drop
        drop(e) {
          let colorId = e.dataTransfer.getData("color_id"); //id of the color (red, yellow...)
          let colorEl = e.dataTransfer.getData("box_el"); //element of the color
          let box1 = document.getElementById("box-1");

          box1.classList.add(colorId);

          if (box1.classList.length > 2) { //I only want one color-class in the container
            box1.classList.remove(box1.classList[1]);
          }
        },
        //second container drop
        drop2(e) {
          let colorId = e.dataTransfer.getData("color_id"); //id of the color (red, yellow...)
          let colorEl = e.dataTransfer.getData("box_el"); //element of the color
          let box2 = document.getElementById("box-2");

          box2.classList.add(colorId);
          if (box2.classList.length > 2) {
            box2.classList.remove(box2.classList[1]);
          }
        }
      },
      computed: {
        evFlower() {
          let box1 = document.getElementById("box-1");
          let box2 = document.getElementById("box-2");
          let box3 = document.getElementById("box-3");
          if (
            box1.classList.contains("Cosmos-red") &&
            box2.classList.contains("Cosmos-yellow")
          ) {
              box3.classList.add("Cosmos-orange");
          }
        }
      }
```

CSS

```
.box-flex {
  height: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}
.box,
.box-1,
.box-2 {
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.Cosmos-red {
  background: red;
}

.Cosmos-yellow {
  background: yellow;
}

.Cosmos-orange {
  background: orange;
}
```

I've tried with a watcher but haven't found a way to 'watch' on DOM changes.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: No need to thank on stack overflow, it makes the content harder to read. Please edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are over complicating things, it is better to avoid DOM manipulations unless it is strictly needed.

It is a better solution to add inline styles, or switch classes on the vue templates with reactive data instead of adding and removing classes directly on the DOM as you'd do with the old Jquery.

This is reactive, easy and cheap to control:

```js
 <div :style="{ background: box1}"></div>
```

I've rewrited your code following this rules:

```html
<template>
  <div>
  <div class="box-flex">
      <div class="box" @dragover.prevent @drop="drop" id="box-1" :style="{ background: box1}"></div>
      <div class="box" @dragover.prevent @drop="drop2" id="box-2" :style="{ background: box2}"></div>
      <div class="box" :style="{ background: box3}"></div>
  </div>
<!-- the elements I want to drag -->
<div v-for="(flower, i) in flowers" :key="i">
  <div>
    <p>{{ flower.type }}</p>

    <p v-for="(color, j) in flower.colors" :key="j">
      <span
        :id="color"
        :draggable="true"
        @dragstart="dragStart"
        @dragover.stop
      >{{ color }}</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>

export default {

  name: 'Intro',

  components: {
  },

  data() {
    return {
      //flowers
      flowers: [
        {
          type: "Cosmos",
          colors: ["red", "yellow", "orange", "black", "pink", "white"]
        },
      ],
      box1: 'white',
      box2: 'white',
      box3: 'white',
    };
  },

  methods: {
    dragStart(e) {
      let target = e.target;
      e.dataTransfer.setData("color_id", target.id);
      e.dataTransfer.setData("box_el", target);
    },
    //first container drop
    drop(e) {
      this.box1 = e.dataTransfer.getData("color_id");
      if ( this.box1 == 'red' && this.box2 == 'yellow') {
        this.box3 = 'orange'
      }
      else {
        this.box3 = 'white'
      }
    },
    //second container drop
    drop2(e) {
      this.box2 = e.dataTransfer.getData("color_id");
      if ( this.box1 == 'red' && this.box2 == 'yellow') {
        this.box3 = 'orange'
      }
      else {
        this.box3 = 'white'
      }
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

```cs
<style>
.box-flex {
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}
.box,
.box-1,
.box-2 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.Cosmos-red {
  background: red;
}

.Cosmos-yellow {
  background: yellow;
}

.Cosmos-orange {
  background: orange;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Yes! That's exactly it.